# tags not showing on custom post type single page

Tags: tags

I have a single-events.php and in there i want to show the tags on that post.

I have tried using this  but nothing comes up.

I have put it within the loop but still nothing.

This is my code

```
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>   
<?php get_template_part( 'content', 'single' ); ?>
<h2>Tags</h2>
<?php the_tags(); ?>
<?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
```

Am i missing something?

Comment: is it the default `post_tags` and not a custom taxonomy?

Comment: Please post your `register_post_type()` code as well. We need to know what taxonomies your CPT supports.

Answer (score 3):

You cant display tags on a custom post type if that custom post type doesn't have tags registered. By default the Tags taxonomy is assigned to posts, you will need to register your post type accordingly.

To do so, use the `taxonomies` parameter:

> **taxonomies**
>
> *(array) (optional)* An array of registered taxonomies like `category` or `post_tag` that will be used with this post type. This can be used in lieu of calling `register_taxonomy_for_object_type()` directly. Custom taxonomies still need to be registered with `register_taxonomy()`.
>
> Default: no taxonomies

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type

Comment: if the cpt didn't have tags registered, they wouldn't have been able to associate terms with the post that they're now expecting to see on a single cpt page, so it doesn't entirely make sense that this would be the issue